# Numpy: replace RGB color at specific indexes

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a Numpy Array of an image and I need to only replace the RGB color of specific elements.

E.G.: If I have 10 elements in the Array with the color rgb(16, 16, 16), I want to replace the color of the 2nd and 7th elements only.

How to do this?

## What I have so far replace them all:

```
r1, g1, b1 = 124, 252, 0 # original
r2, g2, b2 = 255, 255, 255 # new
red, green, blue = img_array[:,:,0], img_array[:,:,1], img_array[:,:,2]
mask = (red == r1) & (green == g1) & (blue == b1)
img_array[:,:,:3][mask] = [r2, g2, b2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to check without a working example img_array.  But if I'm not mistaken, you should be able to get the indeces of the masked values like so :

```
masked_indeces = np.where(img_array[:,:,:3][mask])
```

And then you can choose which of the indeces you want to change in the img_array.